# How to change chart position in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I currently have a script that takes data, formats it, and creates a chart below the data.

I know how to move the chart within the tab using `setPosition`, but can't figure out how to write the chart to a different tab (to create a 'dashboard' where you wouldn't have to see all of the source data). Any ideas on this?

I've tried changing what's in `.setPosition`, but that only moves the chart within the existing tab.

I've also had glitches with this where I've gotten the chart to move to the right of the data in some cases, but using the same code in a different sheet it doesn't write the chart at all.

*Here's the code I'm working with:*

```
var chartTitle = columnHeader;
  if (typeof subtitle[columnHeader] != 'undefined') {
    chartTitle = chartTitle + " - " + subtitle[columnHeader];
  }

  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)

  .setOption('chartArea', {left:'10%',top:'15%',width:'80%',height:'70%'})
  .setPosition(4 + output.length, 1, 0, 0)
  .setOption('width', width)
  .setOption('height', 500)
  .setOption('title', chartTitle)
  .setOption('legend', {position: 'top'});

  var statFormat = {CPC: 'currency', CTR: 'percent', Impressions: 'decimal', Searches: 'decimal'};

  if (statsInChart.length == 0) {
    chartBuilder.setOption('vAxes', {
      // Adds titles to the axis.
      0: {title: columnHeader} });
  } else if (statsInChart.length == 1) {
    chartBuilder.setOption('vAxes', {
      // Adds titles to both axes.
      0: {title: columnHeader} ,
      1: {title: statsInChart[0], format: statFormat[statsInChart[0]]}});
  } else {
    chartBuilder.setOption('vAxes', {
      // Adds title to the first axis, blanks the others.
      0: {title: columnHeader} ,
      1: {format: statFormat[statsInChart[0]], textPosition: 'in'},
      2: {format: statFormat[statsInChart[1]], textPosition: 'out'},
      3: {textStyle: {color: 'white'}}
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? Do you want to move the existing chart to other tab in the same Spreadsheet? Or do you want to create new chart to tab "B" using the data of tab "A"? If it's the latter, can you provide the whole script for creating the chart? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided does not cover when you actually build the chart, nor when you insert it into a sheet.

When you create the `EmbeddedChartBuilder` by calling the `sheet.newChart()` method, you have a `sheet` object that's associated with a particular sheet within the spreadsheet.

**What you want to do is call the `insertChart()` method with a different sheet object, one that is associated with the sheet where you'd like the chart to appear.**

Here's a small example:

```
function createChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName('chart');

  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();

  var chart = chartSheet.newChart()
      .addRange(dataRange)
      .setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0)
      .build();

  chartSheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

In my test spreadsheet, I have two sheets. One is named `data` and it contains a small table of data. The other is a blank sheet named `chart`.

When I execute the above function, a chart is placed in the `chart` sheet based on the data extracted from the `data` sheet.